# error: use of moved value - should I use "&" or "mut" or something else?

Tags: rust

My code:

```
enum MyEnum1 {
  //....
}

struct Struct1 { 
  field1: MyEnum1,
  field2: String
}

fn fn1(a: Struct1, b: String, c: String) -> String {
  let let1 = fn2(a.field1);
  let let2 = fn3(let1, b, c);
  format!("{} something 123 {}", let1, let2)
}


fn fn2(a: MyEnum1) -> String {
  //....   
}

fn fn3(a: MyEnum1, b: Struct1) -> String {
  //....   
}


error: use of moved value: `a.field1`
error: use of moved value: `let1`
```

How can I fix them? Should I add `&` to the parameters of 'fn2`and`fn3`? Or`mut`? I can't understand the idea of how to fix these kind of errors.

Comment: your code produces different errors than you describe, please provide a working example

Comment: Your code is inconsistent. `fn3` declaration does not agree with how it is invoked. This code would give you type errors, not ownership ones. Please make your code [a compilable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

These errors come from the most important concept in Rust - ownership. You should read [the official book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/), especially the chapter on [ownership](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html) - this would help you understand "how tho fix this kind of errors".

In short, specifically in your code, the problem is that `String` is a non-copyable type, that is, `String` values are not copied when passed to functions or assigned to local variables, they are *moved*. This means that wherever they were before, they are not accessible from there anymore.

Let's look at your function:

```
enum MyEnum1 {
  //....
}

struct Struct1 { 
  field1: MyEnum1,
  field2: String
}

fn fn1(a: Struct1, b: String, c: String) -> String {
  let let1 = fn2(a.field1);
  let let2 = fn3(let1, b, c);
  format!("{} something 123 {}", let1, let2)
}

fn fn2(a: MyEnum1) -> String {
  //....   
}
```

All types here are not automatically copyable (they don't implement `Copy` trait). `String` is not copyable because it is a heap-allocated string and copying would need a fresh allocation (an expensive operation which better be not implicit), `MyEnum1` is not copyable because it does not implement `Copy` (with `#[deriving(Copy, Clone)]`, for example; and it is unclear if it can be made copyable because you didn't provide its variants), and `Struct1` is not copyable because it contains non-copyable types.

In `fn1` you invoke `fn2`, passing it `field1` and getting a `String` back. Then you immediately passes this `String` to `fn3`. Because `String` is not copyable, whatever is stored in `let1` is *moved* into the called function, making `let1` inaccessible. This is what "use of moved value" error is about. (The code you provided can't cause "use of moved value: `a.field1`" error, so it probably came from the parts you omitted, but the basic idea is absolutely the same)

There are several ways to fix these errors, but the most natural and common one is indeed to use borrowed references. In general if you only want to read some non-copyable value in a function you should pass it there by reference:

```
fn use_myenum(e: &MyEnum1)
```

For strings and arrays, however, the better way would be to pass slices:

```
fn use_str(s: &str) { ... }

let s: String = ...;
use_str(&s);  // here &String is automatically converted to &str
```

You can find more on slices in the book, [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/strings.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need. One thing: how do I derefence `e` in `fn use_myenum(e: &MyEnum1)` - convert from a pointer to a "normal" MyEnum1?

Comment: Because when I'm trying  to use `*e` I get "error: cannot move out of borrowed content"

Comment: even if this is the answer you were looking for, it would still be great if you updated your question to include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @jawanam, you can't just write `*e` and get the value of the enum because it is not copyable. You can match on the enum variant, it can be done if you don't move any values out of the variant: `match *e { MyEnum1::Variant1 => { ... } MyEnum1::Variant2(ref x, _) => { ... }`.

Comment: @jawanam, or, if you can make the enum copyable (with `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]`, for example), then writing `*e` will just work.