# How to push a value to a Vec and append it to a String at the same time?

Tags: rust

I want to write a program that sets the shell for the system's nslookup command line program:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    let mut newstr = String::from("nslookup");
    for arg in std::env::args() {
        v.push(arg);
        newstr.push_str(&format!(" {}", arg));
    }
    println!("{:?}", v);
    println!("{}", newstr);
}
```

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `arg`
 --> src/main.rs:6:41
  |
5 |         v.push(arg);
  |                --- value moved here
6 |         newstr.push_str(&format!(" {}", arg));
  |                                         ^^^ value borrowed here after move
  |
  = note: move occurs because `arg` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

How to correct the code without traversing `env::args()` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the order of the lines that use `arg`:

```
for arg in std::env::args() {
    //newstr.push_str(&format!(" {}", arg));
    write!(&mut newstr, " {}", arg);
    v.push(arg);
}
```

`Vec::push` takes its argument by value, which moves ownership of `arg` so it can't be used anymore after `v.push(arg)`. `format!` and related macros implicitly borrow their arguments, so you can use `arg` again after using it in one of those.

If you really needed to move the same `String` to two different locations, you would need to add `.clone()`, which copies the string. But that's not necessary in this case.

Also note that `format!` creates a new `String`, which is wasteful when all you want is to add on to the end of an existing `String`. If you add `use std::fmt::Write;` to the top of your file, you can use `write!` instead (as shown above), which is more concise and may be more performant.

### See also

- [What are move semantics in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30288782/3650362)
- [error: use of moved value - should I use "&" or "mut" or something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30972695/3650362)
- [Does println! borrow or own the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30450399/3650362)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that:

```
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = std::env::args().collect();
    let s = args.join(" ");

    println!("{}", s);
}
```

First, you create the vector, and then you create your string.